# Using multiple sequence in Factory-girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am carrying out a test for a feature which requires a user factory. I am having a problem with defining factory with multiple sequence like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  sequence(:username, 1, aliases: [:sender, :receiver]) { |n| "user#{n}"};
  sequence(:email, 1, aliases: [:sender, :receiver]) { |n| "user#{n}@example.com"};

  factory :user do
    username
    email
    password "secret"
    password_confirmation "secret"
    role "1"
  end

end
```

So far this is what i am trying to achieve but it fails with this error message - **"Sequence already registered: sender (FactoryGirl::DuplicateDefinitionError)"** when i run the test.

i have tried several other ways but can't seem to achieve it. It works with only one sequence but fails when i try with two. I understand the error message besides I am using factory-girl for the first time and would appreciate some clarification on how to achieve it.

Comment: Why do you need these `aliases`? I guess should read the docs again. Copy-paste is evil.

Comment: Sorry for the evil. I am learning the turns. Please advise better on the aliases

Comment: You simply don't need them.

Comment: i removed them and it worked. But subsequent users creation fails with error "Validation failed: Email has already been taken, Username has already been taken". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
   FactoryGirl.define do
      sequence :email do |n| 
        "email#{n}@factory.com"
      end 

      sequence :username do |n| 
        "testuser#{n}"
      end 

      factory :user do
        username
        email
        password "secret"
        password_confirmation "secret"
        role "1"
      end

    end
```

Comment: The sequence is faiing to increment the number for the next user

Answer (score 0):

Your error, `FactoryGirl::DuplicateDefinitionError`, is from the duplicate alias names of `:sender` and also of `:receiver`. I assume you copied those from the FactoryBot docs, and can simply remove them.

If you don't have some other reason to define the sequence outside the factory, I would pull it in, something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:username) { |n| "user#{n}"}
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@example.com"}
    password "secret"
    password_confirmation "secret"
    role "1"
  end
end
```

If you depend on the number in the username to be the same as in the email (maybe you don't...) then it's better to ensure that explicitly. It is possible for sequences to get out of sync. Something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:username) { |n| "user#{n}" }
    email { "#{username}@example.com"}
    password "secret"
    password_confirmation "secret"
    role "1"
  end
end
```